# Postgresql how to cast string which is array to array?

Tags: postgresql, clickhouse

Hi I have a field which is jsonb converted to string,sent to clickhouse and stored there as text.

It is created as:

`jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('keyA', valueA, 'keyB' ,valueB))::text`

What I have in return is `[{'keyA':'valueA,'keyB',valueB'}]`

The thing is postgresql FDW to clickhouse converts array in this string  `[ { } ]` to `{ {} }` (with double curly brackets replacing carets) and so I have a string `'{{'keyA':'valueA,'keyB',valueB'}}'` and stores it this way (since clickhouse doesn't support arrays and jsons datatypes). I am 100% sure that it is a string `'[{}]'` at the time of conversion and have no reasonable explanation why string is converted to another string in this strange manner, replacing array datatype.

Then I select it in Postgresql via FDW and it shows me an error.

How do I either convert this string in postgresql to array or jsonb from string or force it to save it like `[ { } ]` when sent to clickhouse?

Comment: Looks like something is transforming it to a Postgres array which uses `'{}'` per [Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) 8.15.2. Array Value Input. You will need to update your question to explain further what '...postgresql FDW to clickhouse...' means?

Comment: Clickhouse supports arrays.

Comment: @DennyCrane rebuilt my table with Array as dataType as you mentioned. Now I get this error 

SQL Error [2F000]: ERROR: clickhouse_fdw:Code: 130, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Array does not start with '[' character: (at row 1). PG field is created via array_agg or jsonb agg, no matter. It sends '{{ }}' not '[{ }]'